# "ikm" must be at least one byte in length

Tags: next.js, next-auth

https://next-auth.js.org/errors#get_authorization_url_error "ikm" must be at least one byte in length {
message: '"ikm" must be at least one byte in length',
stack: 'TypeError: "ikm" must be at least one byte in length\n' +

I'm following this example:
https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application

Answer (score 18):

Make sure that your `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` environment variable in your `.env` file is populated. You can grab one here: https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32

If your dev environment is running make sure to restart it after updating the variable!

Comment: I am setting my NEXTAUTH_SECRET but it still doesn't work still getting the same error

Comment: what AK-35 describes can happen if other relevant values are empty. [see that explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77487779/5011027)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and resolved it by providing **non-empty** value for **JWT_SIGNING_PRIVATE_KEY** and **JWT_SECRET** in .env file

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error on a NextJs Project.
Corrected after setting a value of the variable **NEXTAUTH_SECRET** in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

make sure that the [...nextauth].ts defines the secrets correctly

## Explanation

NextAuth looks up the secrets:

```
# in NextAuthApiHandler

  (_options$secret = options.secret) !== null && _options$secret !== void 0 ? _options$secret : options.secret = (_options$jwt$secret = (_options$jwt = options.jwt) === null || _options$jwt === void 0 ? void 0 : _options$jwt.secret) !== null && _options$jwt$secret !== void 0 ? _options$jwt$secret : process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;
```

So it's using secrets in the following order:

```
options.secret
options.jwt.secret
process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
```

the options are taken from:

```
# [...nextauth].ts

...
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
  },
...
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
...
```

thus, you need to make sure that the .env file ([especially if there are more than one](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)) defines the values correctly which are being used at these places - an empty value isn't sufficient - `openssl rand -hex 32` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same error. and it turns out that the problem is only in the length of NEXTAUTH_SECRET in the .env file. I tried a longer password and it worked.